# What metal is used to cut Vibranium?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

In *WandaVision* the SWORD members dismantle the body of Vision using some machines. As we know that his body is made up of vibranium I would like to know what metal is used to cut through vibranium.

Comment: More Vibranium?

Comment: In the real world, steel cuts steel every day -- not even just in machine tools, but a file or hacksaw is steel cutting steel powered by mere human muscle.

Comment: Vibranium isn't indestructible. A combination of Vision's forehead laser, Tony's repulsors, and Thor's lightning began to melt Ultron's vibranium body after relatively short exposure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know what SWORD used when dissecting Vision's body and putting him back together a thousand times. However, vibranium isn't as strong as you state... though of course it is the strongest metal on Earth.

Leading with that it is only the strongest metal on Earth (*Avengers: Age of Ultron*) and we know that there are other metals that are stronger: Uru, for example, and also whatever Thanos' sword was made out of and Corvus Glaive's glaive. SWORD are also an organisation that exists outside of just Earth and works with at least the Skrulls, they clearly have access to some more advanced tech. It's not unfeasible that they could cut through vibranium.

Next we should note that Vision is not 100% vibranium, he was made from *"wires and blood and bone"*. He was mixed with vibranium but also real tissue created from Helen's cradle.

> **Helen Cho:** The Regeneration Cradle prints tissue; it can’t build a living body.
>
> **Ultron:** It can, you can. You lacked the materials.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

Vibranium also has weaknesses, enough force from anything and it could penetrate it. Also as shown in *Black Panther* it is vulnerable to sonic based equipment such as Wakandan Maglev Train.

This is all of course ruling out whether or not they used more vibranium to cut through it which is a possibility as well with the Wakandans relationship with the Avengers and so likely SWORD now too. But in conclusion we don't know what was used to cut Vision up we just see a selection of hand tools being used or laying about.

[image: SWORD members cut up Vision's body]

Comment: There's also that you don't necessarily use a _metal_ to cut; diamond saws are used for cutting many tough materials (including diamonds).

Comment: @David yes, and the reason we don't make weapons or armor out of diamond is that it is *too* rigid - a diamond sword would just shatter rather than bend when struck by another object. Metals tend to be both reasonably strong *and* pliable. You need both to make effective melee weapons.